# Why there is a Totals row?

Tags: sql-order-by

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why does sql show Total trips in the table below? I tried it with other data set (london_bicycles) and it didn't have this issue.
Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT
     end_station_name
    ,Count (*) as trips  
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY(end_station_name) 
ORDER BY trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSHoo.png)

Comment: I'd say those are all the trips where `end_station_name` is NULL. Just add `WHERE end_station_name IS NOT NULL` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked